# Does Theano actually use 100% of the CPU when it is configured to use the GPU?

Tags: theano

I noticed that when I configure Theano to use the GPU, and run some scripts, the CPU is ~100% used:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5927 jjjjjj    20   0  0.259t 0.025t  83228 R 100.2 20.2  33025:42 python
 8259 jjjjjj    20   0  0.239t 5.303g 102876 R 100.2  4.2   8209:45 python
 7791 jjjjjj    20   0  0.239t 5.086g 102872 R  99.8  4.0   8209:36 python
 7761 jjjjjj    20   0  0.239t 5.193g 104604 R  99.5  4.1   7267:47 python
```

Does this mean that the CPU is the bottleneck? I.e., should I infer that if I replace the CPU with a CPU that has a higher frequency, the script will run faster? Or could it be that the bottleneck is somewhere else and the CPU is actively waiting? If both are a possibility, how do I know which one is the bottleneck?

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
Tue Sep 27 13:55:13 2016
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   73C    P2    95W / 250W |    207MiB / 12287MiB |     45%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   72C    P2    94W / 250W |    182MiB / 12287MiB |     40%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:82:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   73C    P2    93W / 250W |    207MiB / 12287MiB |     43%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 42%   81C    P2   148W / 250W |  11872MiB / 12287MiB |     79%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      8259    C   python                                         157MiB |
|    1      7791    C   python                                         157MiB |
|    2      7761    C   python                                         157MiB |
|    3      5927    C   python                                       11847MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Theano performs all GPU operations asynchronously, meaning that the function call will not wait for the operation to finish. Synchronization is needed before transferring data between the host and the GPU. By default, synchronization is performed by polling the GPU in a busy loop. Consequently, the operating system will always show 100 % CPU usage, even if the program is GPU bound.

Setting the `gpuarray.sched=multi` flag causes the CPU thread to go to sleep while waiting for the GPU to finish computing. You can use this to check if your program is actually CPU or GPU bound. It takes a little bit more time to wake up, but then your CPU is available for other processes while waiting for the GPU.

Note that `ps` shows the CPU usage during the entire lifetime of a process. So if your program first does something on CPU before using Theano, the displayed CPU usage will be high. You can get the current value using `top -p <PID>`.